# Comparing variances: Cramer-Rao estimate vs. calculated variance of ML estimator.

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a n-element sample from the Rayleigh distribution, $$f(x)=\frac{x}{a^2}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2a^2}}$$

and using the method of maximum likelihood, I find the estimator of $a$ to be $$\hat{a}=\frac{X_{rms}}{\sqrt{2}}$$

where $X_{rms}=\sqrt{ \frac{X_1 ^2 +... +X_n ^2}{n}}$ is the root mean square of the sample.

Using the Cramer-Rao theorem, the variance of that estimator is estimated by $$\hat{V}[\hat{a}]=\frac{X^2_{rms}}{8n}$$

By direct calculation, I find $$E[\hat{a}]=a \frac{\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2})}{\sqrt{n}\cdot \Gamma(n)}:=a\cdot p_n$$

so the estimator is asymptotically unbiased because $p_n \rightarrow 1$.

For the variance, direct calculation gives $E[\hat{a}^2]=a^2$, therefore

$$V[\hat{a}]=a^2(1-p^2 _n)$$

I'm supposed to *compare* the two results for the variance - but what exactly could that mean?

My best guess is to calculate $E[\hat{V}[\hat{a}]] = \frac{a^2}{4n}$ and compare this with $a^2(1-p_n ^2)$ . To do that, I would need to have some idea about the asymptotic behaviour of $p^2 _n $, but I didn't study asymptotics yet.

I'm not sure what sort of argument to make here or indeed what is asked of me in this problem.